# How to make it possible to have 2 adjacent operators?

Tags: java

> Check the correctness of the entered expression (there should not be 2 signs of mathematical operations in a row, for example, the expression `3+*4` is not allowed, at the same time, the expression `4*-7` is valid)

I have to add a 2 character exception for `*-` and `/-` in this code

```
public class Main extends Boolean{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String expressionText = scanner.nextLine();
        List<Lexeme> lexemes = lexAnalyze(expressionText);
        LexemeBuffer lexemeBuffer = new LexemeBuffer(lexemes);
        System.out.println(expr(lexemeBuffer));
    }

    public enum LexemeType {
        LEFT_BRACKET, RIGHT_BRACKET,
        OP_PLUS, OP_MINUS, OP_MUL, OP_DIV,
        NUMBER,
        EOF;
    }

    public static class Lexeme {
        LexemeType type;
        String value;

        public Lexeme(LexemeType type, String value) {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Lexeme(LexemeType type, Character value) {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value.toString();
        }


    }

    public static class LexemeBuffer {
        private int pos;

        public List<Lexeme> lexemes;

        public LexemeBuffer(List<Lexeme> lexemes) {
            this.lexemes = lexemes;
        }

        public Lexeme next() {
            return lexemes.get(pos++);
        }

        public void back() {
            pos--;
        }

        public int getPos() {
            return pos;
        }
    }

    public

 

    static List<Lexeme> lexAnalyze(String expText) {
                Boolean bool = new Boolean();
                ArrayList<Lexeme> lexemes = new ArrayList<>();
                int pos = 0;
                while (pos< expText.length()) {
                    char c = expText.charAt(pos);
                    switch (c) {
                        case '(':
                            lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.LEFT_BRACKET, c));
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        case ')':
                            lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.RIGHT_BRACKET, c));
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        case '+':
                            lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.OP_PLUS, c));
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        case '-':
                            lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.OP_MINUS, c));
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        case '*':
                            lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.OP_MUL, c));
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        case '/':
                            lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.OP_DIV, c));
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        default:
                            if (c <= '9' && c >= '0') {
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                do {
                                    sb.append(c);
                                    pos++;
                                    if (pos >= expText.length()) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    c = expText.charAt(pos);
                                } while (c <= '9' && c >= '0');
                                lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.NUMBER, sb.toString()));
                            } else {
                                if (c != ' ') {
                                    System.out.println("Error");
                                    bool.bool = false;
                                    System.out.println(bool.bool);
                                }
                                pos++;
                            }
                    }
                }
                lexemes.add(new Lexeme(LexemeType.EOF, ""));
                return lexemes;
            }
        
            public static int expr(LexemeBuffer lexemes) {
                Lexeme lexeme = lexemes.next();
                if (lexeme.type == LexemeType.EOF) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    lexemes.back();
                    return plusminus(lexemes);
                }
            }
        
            public static int plusminus(LexemeBuffer lexemes) {
            Boolean bool = new Boolean();
                int value = multdiv(lexemes);
                while (true) {
                    Lexeme lexeme = lexemes.next();
                    switch (lexeme.type) {
                        case OP_PLUS:
                            value += multdiv(lexemes);
                            break;
                        case OP_MINUS:
                            value -= multdiv(lexemes);
                            break;
                        case EOF:
                        case RIGHT_BRACKET:
                            lexemes.back();
                            return value;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            bool.bool = false;
                            System.out.println(bool.bool);
                    }
                }
            }
        
            public static int multdiv(LexemeBuffer lexemes) {
                Boolean bool = new Boolean();
                int value = factor(lexemes);
                while (true) {
                    Lexeme lexeme = lexemes.next();
                    switch (lexeme.type) {
                        case OP_MUL:
                            value *= factor(lexemes);
                            break;
                        case OP_DIV:
                            value /= factor(lexemes);
                            break;
                        case EOF:
                        case RIGHT_BRACKET:
                        case OP_PLUS:
                        case OP_MINUS:
                            lexemes.back();
                            return value;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            bool.bool = false;
                            System.out.println(bool.bool);
                    }
                }
            }
        
            public static int factor(LexemeBuffer lexemes) {
                Boolean bool = new Boolean();
                Lexeme lexeme = lexemes.next();
                switch (lexeme.type) {
                    case NUMBER:
                        return Integer.parseInt(lexeme.value);
                    case LEFT_BRACKET:
                        int value = plusminus(lexemes);
                        lexeme = lexemes.next();
                        if (lexeme.type != LexemeType.RIGHT_BRACKET) {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            bool.bool = false;
                            System.out.println(bool.bool);
                        }else {
                            bool.bool=true;
                            System.out.println(bool.bool);
                            return value;
                        }
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error");
                        bool.bool = false;
                        System.out.println(bool.bool);
        
                }
                return 0;
            }
        
        
        }
```

Comment: What about `3+-4` (= -1)?  That should be valid as well.  You have to distinguish between binary operators, two of which cannot appear together, and _unary_ operators.  This is actually a subtle problem, since some situations are ambiguous.  Another example is `3-+4`, which is also equal to -1.

Comment: Any reasonable implementation will also allow `3+--4` and `3----2`, which are perfectly well-formed expressions. This isn't about exceptions for specific sequences of characters; this is about understanding how we as humans parse that expression and writing a program to do the same.

Comment: Jim Garrison, it is true too

Comment: I don't know why you're being asked to do this. Compilers don't. You don't need to check for this case specifically. It will just come out as a syntax error from your parser, as it won't be able to find a valid continuation from the first operator.